# Pandas - Get a row of data when looping through groupBy results

Tags: python, pandas

With the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,1,2],"name":['a','b','a','c'],"val_1":[1,2,3,4],"val_2":[5,6,7,8]})
>>> df
   id name  val_1  val_2
0   1    a      1      5
1   2    b      2      6
2   1    a      3      7
3   2    c      4      8
```

I'm grouping the data frame by id and name, so I can loop through each group data one at a time:

```
>>> grp = df.groupby(['id','name'])
<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x103334c88>
```

Now I'm iterating through the rows of each group and printing it out:

```
>>> for name,group in grp:
...     for row,data in group.iterrows():
...             print(data)
... 
id       1
name     a
val_1    1
val_2    5
Name: 0, dtype: object
id       1
name     a
val_1    2
val_2    6
Name: 1, dtype: object
id       2
name     b
val_1    3
val_2    7
Name: 2, dtype: object
id       2
name     c
val_1    4
val_2    8
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

The rows I want to get are:

```
   id name  val_1  val_2
0   1    a      1      5
   id name  val_1  val_2
1   1    a      2      6
   id name  val_1  val_2
2   2    b      3      7
   id name  val_1  val_2
3   2    c      4      8
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you ultimately want to do within each loop?  There may be a way to accomplish that without the explicit for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to process each group rows one at a time, I'm using the groupby to fix my input data, so it will be ordered by the logical groups, then go over all the rows of each group one by one, and calculate a new vector

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `df.sort_values(['id','name'])` and then go through the `DataFrame` instead?

Comment: Sounds much better, thanks for helping a noob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the print to:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(data).T)
```

Comment: That was my thought but it seems quite inefficient.  I agree with the comment - depends on what OP wants the answer might be markedly different.

Comment: Yeah, I will use the sort_values method. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [1949]: for k in grp.groups.keys():
      ...:     print(grp.get_group(k))
      ...:     
   id name  val_1  val_2
0   1    a      1      5
2   1    a      3      7
   id name  val_1  val_2
1   2    b      2      6
   id name  val_1  val_2
3   2    c      4      8
```